# std::async - argument vector is corrupted

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, vector

I want to split a vector into small vectors, process each of them separately on a thread, then merge them. I want to use `std::async` for creating threads and my code looks something like this

```
void func(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
   //do some stuff
}

// Calling part
std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> temps;
for (int i = 1; i <= threadCount; ++i)
{
    auto& curBegin = m_vec.begin() + (i - 1) * size / threadCount;
    auto& curEnd = m_vec.begin() + i * size / threadCount;
    std::vector<int> tmp(curBegin, curEnd);
    temps.push_back(std::move(tmp));

    futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &func, std::ref(temps.back())));
}
for (auto& f : futures)
{
    f.wait();
}

std::vector<int> finalVector;
for (int i = 0; i < temps.size() - 1; ++i)
{
    std::merge(temps[i].begin(), temps[i].end(), temps[i + 1].begin(), temps[i + 1].end(), std::back_inserter(finalVector));
}
```

Here `m_vec` is the main vector, which is being split into small vectors.
The problem is that when I pass a vector to `func()`, in function it becomes invalid, either size is 0 or with invalid elements. But when I try to call the function without `std::async` everything works fine.

So what's the problem with `std::async` and is there anything special that I should do?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a *reallocation* happens while you're iteratively expanding the `temps` vector, then it's very likely `std::ref(temps.back())` that the thread operates on is referencing an already invalidated memory area. You can avoid relocations by reserving the memory prior to consecutive `push_back`s:

```
temps.reserve(threadCount);
```

Answer (score 3):

Piotr S. has already given a correct answer with a solution, I will just add some explanation.

> So what's the problem with std::async and is there anything special that I should do?

The problem is not with `async`.

You would get exactly the same effect if you did:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> futures;
// ...
for (int i = 1; i <= threadCount; ++i)
{
  // ...
  futures.push_back(std::bind(&func, std::ref(temps.back())));
}
for (auto f : futures)
  f();
```

In this version I don't use `async`, I create several function objects then run them all one by one. You will see the same problem with this code, which is that the function objects (or in your case, the tasks being run by `async`) hold references to vector elements that get destroyed when you insert into `temps` and cause it to reallocate.

To solve the problem you need to ensure the elements in `temps` are stable, i.e. do not get destroyed and recreated at a different location, as Piotr S shows in his answer.